# Multiple use of string::find at the same string

Tags: c++, string

This is a program that extracts data from a string.

```
size_t pos;
string str = "2,1,4,9,5";
string str1 = str;
```

Deleting from second comma to end:

```
for (int i = 0; i<2; i++){
    pos = str1.find(",");
}
str1.erase(str1.begin() + pos, str1.end());
```

Deleting from beginning to first comma:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++){
    pos = str1.find(",");
}
str1 = str1.substr(pos + 1);
```

So now `str1` should be `"1"`

Converting it to int:

```
int digit;
stringstream converter;
converter << str1;
converter >> digit;
cout << digit << endl;
converter.clear();
```

I realized that `str1` is not equal to "1" because at `str1.find(",")` it did't start searching from beginning, but it started from where it left of.

My question is, how can I make `string::find` search from the beginning of the string, without initializing more strings `str2=str; str3=str;` etc.

Comment: `str1 = str1.substr(pos2 + 1);` where do you define `pos2` ? did you mean `pos` ?

Comment: Actually `find` always start searching from beginning if you don't provide  `pos ` parameter. See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Comment: sorry my mistake, I meant `pos`. fixed it

Comment: Can you provide us with the output your console gives you ? (particularly what do you get when you print str1 ?)

Comment: @user It always prints me the first digit

Comment: @Fanarosss After `str1.erase(str1.begin() + pos, str1.end());` the content is `"2"`. See here http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c45f746af690f45 You have probably some wrong assumptions about how your string looks like aftter that operation.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yeah I got so confused about how it works. I believe if I do my `substr` first it will work.

Comment: @Fanarosss So you realize that `std::string::find()` isn't the culprit.

Comment: @Fanarosss The easiest way would be to parse the whole string into a `std::vector<std::string>` using `std::istringstream` and `std::getline()` with `','` as delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in what you expected this code to perform :

```
for (int i = 0; i<2; i++) {
    pos = str1.find(",");
}
```

> Deleting from second comma to end:

Apparently you thought this would find the first ',' first and then find the second ',' (when i ==1) whereas this will both time find the first ','. The following code :

```
str1.erase(str1.begin() + pos, str1.end());
```

will therefore erase `,1,4,9,5` from your string.

One solution is to replace

```
for (int i = 0; i<2; i++) {
    pos = str1.find(",");
}
```

by

```
pos = str1.find(",", 3);
```

Also replace this (which only executes once)

```
for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
    pos = str1.find(",");
}
```

by this :

```
pos = str1.find_last_of(",");
```

Your goal is to extract one digit, if the wanted digit is not the second digit (like in this particuliar case) you will want to remove all previous digits, so search for the last comma.
It is also good practice to compare `pos` to `string::npos`

Comment: that works but it depends to the problem.
ex. I might have 3 digit numbers, or I want to find the element after the third comma.

Comment: @Fanarosss If i understood you correctly, you'll need to tell your code how to behave : depending on the size of your string, pass a `size_t` argument that tells the function where to start removing digits (and replace `3` by that argument)

Answer (score 0):

string:find is supposed to search from the beginning if you don't specify a starting position.

[std::string::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)